# Common strategies and counters

Tags: starcraft-2

Is there a resource that can give me a list of popular strategies (not builds), and effective counters to them?

E.g. - rush can be countered by wall-in-natural, fast expand countered by rush, etc... ?

Comment: ripper, we have [a meta site](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/) in which we can discuss anything about this site (rather than about games themselves); please avoid such discussions on the main site.

Answer (score 2):

http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Main_Page

Comment: Could you perhaps elaborate on this one? Perhaps just list some of the strategies instead of just posting a link